How do I get Mathematica not to multiply a vector by a scalar elementwise, but leave it as the scalar times the vector
In Mathematica I have the variable u defined as follows:
u = {1,2,3}

Now I want the product a*u to show as:
a {1,2,3}

but a*u returns this:
{a,2 a,3 a}

I have tried HoldForm and other things, but I cannot make it work. Any help?

u = {1, 2, 3};

a u


{a, 2 a, 3 a}

s = Inactivate[a u]


a {1, 2, 3}

Activate[s]


{a, 2 a, 3 a}

InputForm[s]


Inactive[Times][a, {1, 2, 3}]

